# .NET Application reading from SQL Server is slow, when executable and dll's are installed on network drive

Tags: .net, sql-server, performance, networking

I have problems with my .NET application when the application is installed on a network drive.

The application uses SQL Server database with standard .NET adapter. When I start the application from the network drive, communication with the SQL Server database is very slow (read and write data). When I install the same application on a local drive, the communication with the SQL Server database is normal fast.

Does someone know the reason about that and can provide me with a possible solution, that I can run the application from the network drive and communication is equally fast like it is installed and run from local drive?

**Update:**

I have now figured out, that it has to do, who is creating the Network-Folder. I have the first folder, which is causing the application slow created with an admin-User on the server. When I create with the local client-user on the client a new network-folder (on the same share) and copy my application from the first one to the new, it is running fast. Does someone have an idea, why this is the case?

Comment: Is the application equally fast with non-database tasks?  Or is this only a data-driven application?

Comment: It is equally fast with non-database tasks (like starting the application or opening forms usw.). It is only slow when it reads data from the database.

Comment: What does 'usw' mean exactly?  I am going to guessed the connect from the network drive server to the database server is slower then your local network connect to the database drive.  besides the effect your sending the response shared drive -> database -> shareddrive -> local computer.

Comment: I have updated my question with my new finding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out, that the reason is in the rights of the folder. When the current user creating the Network-Folder, the application runs fast. So this is the answer of the first part of the question. I will mark this as answer and searching on, why the rights of the folder are playing this.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you really did due diligence and measured the bottleneck correctly and you have proof that is the *application* that is slow, not the *server*, this could be because the application exercising the code access security for `SqlClientPermission` CAS attributes. Note that this has nothing to do with the persmisison to access the SQL Server, this is CAS. See [Code Access Security and ADO.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x4t63kb%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) for more details.

The one thing I would suspect is that when running from a network share, bacause of the different CAS zone (likely LocalIntranet_zone) the some additional code signing verification is exercised and this is slow due to an expired certificate revocation list and lack of connectivity to the trusted authority revocation list server. See [Fix slow application startup due to code sign validation](http://rusanu.com/2009/07/24/fix-slow-application-startup-due-to-code-sign-validation/) for an explanation. You may give a shot to the fix described in that article.

Otherwise, if is indeed a CAS validation issue, this article has a good description of the CAS tools (altough a bit dated): [Understanding .NET Code Access Security](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/security/UB_CAS_NET.aspx) and you can modify the LocalIntranet_zone settings (but do understand that this is a global change).

Comment: I have updated my question with my new finding. Perhaps you have an idea about that?

Answer (score 0):

If the network share is a file server, then you could have file logging turned on for that server.